# LinqDataSource set isolation level to READ UNCOMMITTED

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Is it possible to somehow set LinqDataSource's IsolationLevel to READ UNCOMMITTED?

I have LinqDataSource bound to pretty nasty SQL Server View (INNER JOIN to multiple tables) and sometimes Deadlock exception is thrown if I load the page with all entries from view while site is under heavy load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `LinqDataSource`, then try setting the isolation level as part of the `DataContext` connection itself (would mean that if you use the same `DataContext` with other code that has different isolation level requirements, you would need to set up different ways of initializing the `DataContext`).

Other options include:

- Open the `DataContext` in your codebehind, and set the transaction level thee
- Access a stored procedure with your `LinqDataSource` or code, through your `DataContext`, and inside the stored procedure manually set the isolation level for the transaction.

See [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingLINQToSQLAndLINQToEntitiesToUseNOLOCK.aspx) for more on there options.

Comment: I've solved the problem by using WITH (NOLOCK) during construction of Sql Server View.